# I have a requirement to check if date given on object is greater than today's but should be less than next 5 business days. How to apply that logic?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, date, js, businesshours

I am able to calculate easily if it is greater than today.

```
setConditionalFormatting(){
        if(this.myTaskWrappers){
            this.myTaskWrappers = this.myTaskWrappers.map(item => {
                console.log('today '+ todayDate);
                console.log('date ' + item.Name +' ' + item.Due_Date__c);
                if(item.Due_Date__c){
                    
                    let iconName = item.Due_Date__c >todayDate ? DUEDATECONDITIONALFORMATTINGPROEPRTIES[0].iconName :" "
                    let dueDateColor = item.Due_Date__c >todayDate ? DUEDATECONDITIONALFORMATTINGPROEPRTIES[0].textColor :" "
                    return {...item, 
                        "dueDateColor":dueDateColor,
                        "iconName":iconName
                    }
                }
                return item;
            });
        }
    }
```

but failing to achieve next 5 business days. I need this logic in JS of LWC component where I can check this condition.
Currently I am just checking if it is greater than today's date but i need it should be less than next 5 business days as well.

Comment: In apex you can use Business Hour class for that purpose, so it might be easier if your JS will call apex method

Comment: but i have to do conditional rendering based on that , that's why logic requir in JS only

Comment: Still you can call server method and render the html based on the result

Comment: thanks @LironC for your input. But i was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the logic I have used in Js to check that it should be less than next 5 business days but greater. than today's date.

```
setConditionalFormatting() {
        if (this.myTaskWrappers) {
          this.myTaskWrappers = this.myTaskWrappers.map(item => {
            console.log('today ' + todayDate);
            console.log('date ' + item.Name + ' ' + item.Due_Date__c);
            if (item.Due_Date__c) {
              let dueDate = new Date(item.Due_Date__c);
              let today = new Date();
      
              let nextBusinessDay = new Date(today);
              let businessDaysCount = 0;
              console.log(nextBusinessDay);
      
              while (businessDaysCount < 1) {
                nextBusinessDay.setDate(nextBusinessDay.getDate() + 1);
      
                if (nextBusinessDay.getDay() !== 0 && nextBusinessDay.getDay() !== 6) {
                  businessDaysCount++;
                  console.log('weekend condition ');
                }
              }
      
              let fifthBusinessDay = new Date(nextBusinessDay);
              businessDaysCount = 0;
      
              while (businessDaysCount < 5) {
                fifthBusinessDay.setDate(fifthBusinessDay.getDate() + 1);
      
                if (fifthBusinessDay.getDay() !== 0 && fifthBusinessDay.getDay() !== 6) {
                  businessDaysCount++;
                }
              }
      
              let iconName = dueDate > today && dueDate <= fifthBusinessDay ? DUEDATECONDITIONALFORMATTINGPROEPRTIES[0].iconName : " ";
              let dueDateColor = dueDate > today && dueDate <= fifthBusinessDay ? DUEDATECONDITIONALFORMATTINGPROEPRTIES[0].textColor : " ";
      
              return {
                ...item,
                "dueDateColor": dueDateColor,
                "iconName": iconName
              };
            }
            return item;
          });
        }
      }
```